# How to convert location date time to date object using Python?

Tags: python, datetime, automation

I want to convert data

Date = '2020-06-30T00:00:00.000+0000'  Needs to convert 2020-06-30 and also  time = 19:10:00   time needs to convert 07:10 pm using Python

Comment: What should the output be for the provided `Date`?

Comment: Have a look into [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: did you have a look at [strftime and strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)? nice format code list at https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date.split('T')[0] # 2020-6-30
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime("19:10", "%H:%M")
d.strftime("%I:%M %p") # "07:10 PM"
```